# NSURLSessionDataTask causes high CPU usage

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm using a `NSURLSessionDataTask` to feed data into an audio stream in the background (not really relevant in this case).

The problem I'm encountering happens with just the downloading code - I've isolated this and simply discard the data, so no other parts of the system are affecting it.

I've observed that if I create the `NSURLSession` with a config (`NSURLSessionConfiguration`) created using `backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier` then the CPU usage while downloading is low (<5%).  Although this works (95% of the time), I believe it's not a supported configuration.  I also only need this to work when the app is in the foreground.

So, instead, I create the `NSURLSession` with a config created using `ephemeralSessionConfiguration`, this also stops it using the disk as a background cache and should therefore use the least CPU.  However, in this scenario CPU usage rockets to between 70% & 80%.

The same high CPU usage also occurs with config created using `defaultSessionConfiguration` or even getting the shared `NSURLSession` using `[NSURLSession sharedSession]`.

The data throughput is unchanged between each scenario - just not running in the background causes high CPU usage.

I'm running on iOS 9.1 using SDK 9.1.  It happens in both the simulator and on-device.

**Update 16th Nov** - As George pointed out, it appears then the didReceiveData method is thrashed.  The only way I've found to deal with this is to add in a call to

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.25];
```

which seems pretty drastic, but takes the CPU from around 60-80% when downloading, to around 10-12%.  The download is running in it's own thread, so it's only the download that is slowed down.  In fact, it's not really slowed down - the `didReceiveData` just receives data in much larger chunks.  In my app this doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with Mac OS 10.11. 30-50% of one core taken up by downloading a single file. The usage depends on network performance.  It appears that when using the default or ephemeral configurations, the delegate method ``URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveData:``` is called multiple times per **millisecond**! Switching to a background config dials that back considerably.  I've tried playing with the task's priority property but it has no effect in my setup so far. Perhaps if something else was competing for resources it would.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably set the `delegateQueue` of the `NSURLSession` to be a low priority queue (i.e., `dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)`.  I assume the problem is not that processing actually takes more CPU, but that it happens more frequently because the queue it is dispatching to is high priority.